# Open files in table view to other applications

Tags: ios, tableview

So far I have gone through and implemented http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/importing-exporting-documents-ios into my project. However this does nothing. I'm trying to get it to open any file in a supported app.

I have declared both in my .h and .m.

```
.h
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;
@property (retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;
```

and

```
.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellTapSound play];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    [self openDocumentIn];

}

-(void)openDocumentIn {
    NSString * filePath = self.directoryPath = @"/var/mobile/Documents/downloads";
    documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    documentController.delegate = self;
    [documentController retain];
    documentController.UTI = @"public.deb"  @"public.zip" @"public.text" @"com.apple.quicktime-movie" @"com.adobe.pdf";
    [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero
                                           inView:self.view
                                         animated:YES];
}

-(void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
       willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

}

-(void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
          didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

}

-(void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:
(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {

}
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

UPDATE 8/1

So I have managed to get it working, however the only thing that is not happening, is whatever app i choose to open, it doesn't show the file. Dropbox for example. Below is my updated half working code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellTapSound play];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


    NSString *filePath = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    [interactionController setURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
    [interactionController setUTI:@"public.filename-extension"];

    [interactionController setDelegate:self];
    [interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];


}
```

I think I need to declare something somewhere in here, just don't know what.

```
-(void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
       willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

}


-(void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
          didEndSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {

}
```

Stuck again, any ideas?

UPDATE 8/6

Out of noobish dumb luck I got it working :) Posted answer below.

Although nobody answered here I hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: Post updated with new code.

Comment: could you please post .h and .m files.. I am trying the same and documents wouldnt open and dont see any error..

Comment: The .h and .m of what? My documents view controller?

Comment: I got it working.. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, just came back on here. Glad you got it working though :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres what got it working for me.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellTapSound play];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];


    NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my downloads"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    documentController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
    documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    [documentController setDelegate:self];
    [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [documentController retain];
}
```